# How to decide a Pokemon's Hidden Power Type(in X and Y)?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I know there is an [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/whats-a-good-strategy-for-determining-the-type-of-my-pokemons-hidden-power) that explains where the person is, and how to figure it out on your own, but it only Applies to Black and White and some previous games. Is there a person who tells me the type of a hidden ability in X and Y? If so, where is he?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In X/Y, the NPC who will tell you the type a given Pokémon's Hidden Power is located in [Anistar City](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Anistar_City#Hidden_Power_Checker), in the house next to the boutique. He is also the NPC who gives you TM10 (Hidden Power) in the first place.